# In EntityFramework does Take(5) have to come after all Where() clauses?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I had a query set up (lots of conditionals in the code deciding what `Where()` clauses to add.

I found that if I did `Take(5)` and then the `Where()` clauses, I got nothing. But if I put it after the `Where()` clauses, then it works as expected.

Is this by design?

Comment: @gilliduck yes - thank you

Comment: I do not understand reason of this question. Give me 5 records (without order!!) the apply filter on these returned five records.  For sure you may have nothing.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I wasn't thinking this through. I tried to delete the question but can't because there's an answer. So please vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Take(5)` should always go at the end of a query. You are essentially saying, once the query has been executed, to take the first 5 results. I'm not sure what happens if `Take(x)` is executed before `Where()`, but my guess would be it's just selecting the first `x` entries in the database and executing the `Where()` on that, which is not likely to return anything meaningful